# Making a bootable 12.04 Ubuntu Image on a flash drive

Tags: 12.04, usb-drive, iso, bittorrent, convert

1. Downloaded ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads.
2. Downloaded Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.3.exe from http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

3 How do you convert the ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent to the ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso for the flash drive? Just rename the file? Or is there an extraction process through a bit torrent utility -- and if so ---can you point me in the direction on how to do it?

Comment: Use the universal USB installer program you downloaded, give it the ISO and tell it what USB drive and it will install it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: That is a torrent file with which you can download the iso file. You need to open it with torrent client software to be able to get the iso file.

Answer (score 1):

You only have a torrent "seed". You haven't actually downloaded Ubuntu at this point. The official documentation states:

> BitTorrent is a peer-to-peer download network that sometimes enables
>   higher download speeds and more reliable downloads of large files. You
>   will need to **install a BitTorrent client** on your computer in order to
>   enable this download method.

Source: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Comment: Thankd for your help. Sorry I wasn't clear. I need to know if i just rename the ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent file I downloaded to ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso in order to use it -- or do I have to utilize an extraction utility to convert the ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent to ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: -1 This does not answer the question. The OP states they already had the .iso and never asked how to use a bittorrent.

Comment: @MarkKirby - I respectfully ask that you reverse your down vote, as you can see the OP said the same thing in his answer as I did here.

Comment: OK I see that , I overlooked the `.torrent` part of the file name in the question.

Comment: You must edit so I can change my vote, perhaps add a line saying, "you only have a torrent file you must use a torrent client to download Ubuntu with that file" to the beginning of your answer, I would upvote that considering to OP ignored your answer and posted there own exactly the same.

Comment: @MarkKirby - Done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses.

Found out from my IT guy that you need to download and install Bit Torrent (http://www.bittorrent.com/) to download and convert the ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent on the Ubuntu web site to extract the ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso image you need to use in order to install it on a PC. Sadly you can't just rename the file, not is any of this documentation referenced on the page:http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Comment: Exactly. It's just a torrent file, not the ISO itself.

Comment: Yes it does say that right on the page and in the answer above quote:"BitTorrent is a peer-to-peer download network that sometimes enables higher download speeds and more reliable downloads of large files. You will need to install a BitTorrent client on your computer in order to enable this download method." Nowhere does it say "rename the file"